# Foreign Key Constraint 5

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in my database. `TableOne` has `theKey` primary key. `TableTwo` has a foreign key `theKey` that refers to the corresponding column in the `TableOne`. Now I am trying to update `theKey` in `TableTwo`:

```
  UPDATE TableTwo
  SET theKey = NewIk
  FROM TableTwo W
  JOIN TableThree D ON W.theKey_backup = D.OldIk
  WHERE dt >= '2012-05-01'
```

But I receive the following error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_TableTwo_TableOne". The conflict occurred in database "MyDB",
>   table "dbo.TableOne", column 'theKey'.

Could you please explain why I get this error if I don't touch the `TableOne`?

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to set `TableTwo.theKey` to a value that **doesn't exist** in the referenced table, `TableOne` - that's what the error is saying.

Comment: Thanks! Don't you want to make it an answer? I would mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set `TableTwo.theKey` to a value that **doesn't exist** in the referenced table, `TableOne` - that's what the error is saying.

So you need to check why this is happening - where are you selecting that new value from? Why is it a value that doesn't (yet) exist in `TableOne`?